# Getting 0KB of size file while backup mysql database using mysql dump

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I am using below code to backup my database using php script but I am getting 0KB size file. How can I backup my full database with all routines and functions?

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname='mydatabase';
$toDay = date('d-m-Y');
    //exec("mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password='$dbpass' --host=$dbhost --single-transaction $dbname > D:\Sql_Backups/".$toDay."_DB.sql");
    //exec('mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpass --host=$dbhost $dbname > D:\Sql_Backup/file.sql');
      exec ("mysqldump --routines --h $dbhost --u $dbuser --p $dbpass --single-transaction $dbname > D:\Sql_Backup/db3_backup.sql" >
```

Comment: 1st and 2nd exec are commented ??

Comment: @Abdul Manaf there is 3 exec commends 3 are giving same result 0kb size file.

Comment: Your password ($dbpass) is blank, yet you're using the "-p" parameter.  I'm not sure this will work.  If there's no password, don't use the "-p" parameter.  Also - it's single dashes for short versions of switches (-p, -h, -u) - not double dashes (--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a 0KB file for output is becuse of a syntax error in the mysqldump

You have this in the question

```
exec ("mysqldump --routines --h $dbhost --u $dbuser --p $dbpass --single-transaction $dbname > D:\Sql_Backup/db3_backup.sql" > ...
```

Remove the extra dashes from `-h`, `-u`, `-p`

```
exec ("mysqldump --routines -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass --single-transaction $dbname > D:\Sql_Backup/db3_backup.sql" > ...
```

The first two commands you have commented out has double dashes when you spell out the option. That part of the syntax is correct.

## OTHER THINGS TO CHECK

- Make sure the you use the same slashes on the file. Also, check which one of the following works properly in PHP

  - `D:/Sql_Backup/db3_backup.sql`
  - `D:\Sql_Backup\db3_backup.sql`
  - `D:\\Sql_Backup\\db3_backup.sql`
- Make sure `mysqldump.exe` is in the %PATH. If if is not, you make have to use the absolute path by doing something like this:

  exec ("D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.x Server\bin\mysqldump --routines --h $dbhost --u $dbuser --p $dbpass --single-transaction $dbname > D:\Sql_Backup/db3_backup.sql" > ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to write this in php, but you should write mysqldump command like below, there is no need to write three command one is enough

```
mysqldump --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --single-transaction --routines db_name > db_name.sql
```

---

**UPDATE**

I did it here is the php script

```
<?php
define("BACKUP_PATH", "/home/abdul/");

$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "root";
$database_name = "world_copy";
$date_string   = date("Ymd");

$cmd = "mysqldump --routines -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} > " . BACKUP_PATH . "{$date_string}_{$database_name}.sql";

exec($cmd);
?>
```

It generate backup file named as `20140225_world_copy.sql` in `/home/abdul/`

For reference have a look at [**This link.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679275/mysqldump-via-php)

Comment: i tried this one but no use i dont know where i did wrong..

Comment: Check answer now

Comment: @Abduul same result getting 0kb file.

Comment: I can't say what you are trying but it working for me. are you getting any error ?

Comment: it not throw any error it jest giving 0kb file

Comment: Your syntax seems fine (+1). Surendra's syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use the follwoing syntax :**

**Full dump with routines as well**
mysqldump  --routines > outputfile.sql

---

**To dump your routines**
     mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt  > dumpfile.sql

---

-the option --routines is available from verion 5.0.13.
-remember that the backup user need to have the rights to read the routines.

Comment: I am using mysql server version 5.5.36 and root have all rights But still getting same problem getting 0kb size file.

Comment: Try to do is separately, data dump , and ddl dum, and try to use a text pass, don't pass any params.!

Comment: @UPp_One i tried that but no use..

Comment: Place a log on the output to see what is going on ! and posted it !

Answer (score -2):

You need find where the `mysqldump.exe` for backup and mysql.exe for restore is in your computer. Then copy the path to the code: Then create a backup folder to save the backup file.

For backup

$dumpfile");
?>