# 0kb backup using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, python

> Same question has been asked [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/59599/58525) but its not helping me out.

In my `python` utility, I'm trying to take MySQL database backup using `mysqldump`. It runs successfully but I'm getting 0kb file in my backup folder.

This is my code;

```
DB_HOST = '192.168.1.1'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_USER_PASSWORD = '_root_user_password_'
DB_NAME = 'db_name'
BACKUP_PATH = '/backup/dbbackup/'

DATETIME = time.strftime('%m%d%Y-%H%M%S')
TODAYBACKUPPATH = BACKUP_PATH + DATETIME

dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/" + db + ".sql"

os.system(dumpcmd)
```

Can anyone guide me out that what I'm missing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some troubleshooting:

- Run the command (dictated by `dumpcmd`) from the command-line and see if there are any errors
- Does the password have any special characters in it that could mess up in a shell
- Try changing mysqldump to the full path, eg: `/usr/local/bin/mysqldump`
- Check the return value from `os.system()` in your script

Changing to the full path appears to be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same thing but I ran my script on a Windows host and the user running the job in task scheduler did not have admin rights on the machine, or in fact any rights since it was a domain account, and hence produced a 0kb file.